# Document changes before save

Tags: c#, diff, document, envdte

I'm using [EnvDTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.document_properties.aspx) and with that interface I know is document was saved or not (was there any changes).

All I want to know now is there any way to get information like: how many lines was added and how many of them was removed or modified

Answer (score 1):

Look into CodeModel.

[CodeModel Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codemodel.aspx)